# How to get letter "ć" with the dead keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode, dead-keys

I am running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon (64 bit) and want to get letter "ć" using US layout with dead keys.

My current layout is *`US` with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and dead keys*,  Compose key is set to <kbd>Win</kbd>. Here are some example inputs/outputs:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> = "é"

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> =  "æ"

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> =  "ó"

<kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> = "ò"

<kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "è"

I can even get "ç" and "ś" - almost everything, except "ć". What combination do I need?

My */usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8* has the following lines:

```
<dead_cedilla> <c>                  : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <comma> <c>             : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <c> <comma>         : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<Multi_key> <cedilla> <c>           : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

and

```
<dead_acute> <C>                    : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <acute> <C>             : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <C>        : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <C> <apostrophe>        : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<dead_acute> <c>                    : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <acute> <c>             : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <c>        : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<Multi_key> <c> <apostrophe>        : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply press the dead_acute key (to the right of the semicolon) followed by <C>?

Comment: Yes, I have. It gives me **'c** (acute, followed by "c")

Comment: Not for me when I use _English (US, international with dead keys)_. It gives me ć as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set US keyboard layout, not with Dead keys.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> = "ç"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> = "ć"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> = "ś"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "æ"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "œ"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "é"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "è"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> = "à"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> = "ï"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> = "ñ"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> = "ø"

I feel very nostalgic these combinations.

<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> = "â"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> = "ô"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> = "ê"

*J'aime manger un gâteau à l'hôtel.*
*L’accent circonflexe ne disparaîtra pas de sitôt*

Comment: For me, both **Compose + ' c** and  **Compose + ,  c**  give the same result: "ç".
**Compose + ' s** works as expected (i.e. gives "ś").

Comment: I set plain US layout, not with dead key

Comment: I tried plain US and UK, but still it gives me "ç" instead of "ć".

Comment: From terminal please, GUI setting sometime need to reboot or logout/in to take an effect.

Comment: I've made **dpkg-reconfigure**, restarted X-server and  voilà! - it's working:  ćçś.