# How do I write french accents in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.4 and looking a way to write French accents. On Windows I used TypeIt app which provides a fast way to write different accents of the same letter.
The idea is to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> key, each time you press the same key while holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it will type that key with different accents.

For example, I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> once - it types `é`, I keep holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and press <kbd>e</kbd> second time - it types `è`, third time - `ê`.

I was looking on the Internet how to change keys mapping but didn't find a way of assigning multiple different letters based on how many times I pressed a key.

I am aware of US intern. + dead keys, but this way doesn't look convenient for me.

Comment: not clear on what keyboard layout you're using

Answer (score 2):

If you use a standard US keyboard, the easiest way obviously would be to use the US International layout, even if currently, it does not look convenient to you. It provides the most simple approach, using dead keys, to provide accented letters such as ê, é, è. <kbd>Alt_right</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> provides you a ç.

If you do not want the dead keys at times when you do not type French, then you can still set up US International next to your regular keyboard layout, and switch to the US international layout when desired.

Alternatively, the classical Linux way of entering accented letters is by enabling a Compose key. [The compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) allows a wide variety of characters to be entered. It works with your regular keyboard layout. Assuming you use the standard desktop of Ubuntu 20.04, you can set up a compose key in Gnome Tweaks (not installed by default!) on the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab. To use it, press the compose key and then a sequence of characters. If you defined for example left Alt as the compose key, you would enter `ç` as <kbd>left_Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: thanks for the ç!!

Comment: On a German Linux Layout, you can write ç without compose key as a Çedille (pressing AltGr (Right Alt) and the accent key ´ ) followed by c. While there is an æ (AltGr + a), there is no œ which requires pressing Compose-Key + o + e while holding the compose key.

Answer (score 1):

There are some handy packages to manipulate each key and mouse button.
For the packages`xmodmap` `xbindkeys` `xdotool` and `xte` are popular.

`sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils`
`sudo apt install xbindkeys`

Edit `~/.xbindkeysrc` add lines below.  (if there's no such file `xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc` to create one.

```
"xdotool key U00e9"
 AltGr+e+release  

"xdotool key U00e8"
 AltGr+w+e+release
```

Save this file and
`pkill -f xbindkeys && xbindkeys`
execute this command to apply changes.

Now then, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> should type **é** and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> type **è**.
But I am afraid that I haven't tested this. I am not sure this works or not.

---

I love using <kbd>Compose</kbd> key and its combinations.
[How to get letter "ć" with the dead keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906390/how-to-get-letter-%c4%87-with-the-dead-keys/906408#906408)
It depends how often you need an accent letter, if it's only once in a week then I recommend
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and type a hexdecimal number (00e9) then <kbd>Space</kbd>, you get **é**

Comment: thanks for your comment. I learn french and normally write 200+ sentences every day. Unfortunately xbindkeys didn't work for me.  I then just re-assigned keys on my own preference in ` /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us ` under the section ` include "us(basic)"
    name[Group1]= "English (US, intl., with dead keys)";` inspired by https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187917/change-accented-letters-in-international-with-dead-keys-keyboard-layout

Comment: It will do, too. AZERTY is also nice.

Answer (score 0):

And if you do not like to have dead keys in the International layout, please consider the `US International with AltGr dead keys` layout. `AltGr`+`e` will produce `é`, but a single `'` will NOT be dead and produce a `'`. `AltGr`+`'`, however, will be dead. `AltGr`+`"` is also dead, giving you access to ë. The whole story is [here](https://www.choam.eu/altgr-intl/).

Answer (score 0):

********* This does not work fully **************
I found using iBus handy (and I did this on Xubuntu 22.04 using a regular English-US keyboard).  No need to change system keyboard configuration (I tried fooling around with it initially but had no success, so just kept it with English-US).  Just install iBus.  Then in iBus->Perferences->Input Method, add "French - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)".  Then when typing French, click on the iBus icon on the panel and select the above method.  Then the combinations with the right-alt key will produce the accented letters.  The input method also allows to continue typing English text without special operations.

BTW, I did similarly with German by adding "German - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)".

---

Update: The above only gets accented letters, but not graves and so forth.  I had to change the approach, as documented https://xilinjia.github.io/2022/11/12/type-french-german.html

Basically, setting a Compose key via keyboard setting helps.