# How to write a midpoint with an azerty keyboard on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

On the same keyboard with ubuntu 16.04, the midpoint (U+00B7) has been accessible with AltGr + Shift + & (key 1, upper left)

In ubuntu 20.04, none of the combination I've found listed in azerty flavors has been working so far :

- AltGr + ⇧ Maj + ;
- AltGr + ⇧ Maj + 1
- AltGr + :
- ⇧ Maj + AltGr + .
- ⇧ Maj + *

An out of the box 20.04 installation ends up as follows:

```
$ setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols
   xkb_symbols   { include "pc+fr(azerty)+us:2+inet(evdev)" };

$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr,us
variant:    azerty,
```

Do I have to add manually each French specific character like suggested in [How do I write french accents in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266800/how-do-i-write-french-accents-in-ubuntu-20-04) ?

How could I investigate what's different in my configuration between my 16.04 and my 20.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you had some kind of modification on your 16.04 machine.

If you want to do it in a similar way, you can open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` for editing, find this line:

```
key <AE01>  { [ ampersand,  1          ] };
```

in the *French (AZERTY)* section and change it to

```
key <AE01>  { [ ampersand,  1,  U00B7  ] };
```

Then you can do: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd> => ·